# How to get Skeletal Data with RGB Video feed with Kinect SDK using C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect-sdk

I initialized the kinect sensor using NUI_INITIALIZE(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON) to get the skeletal data.

I'm working on Augmented Reality Project where i can display a virtual ball/cube in the video feed that kinect generates by gathering the skeletal data in the background.

I will get the coordinates of hands and i'll render the cube with respect to the hand.

However i can't find a way to have a video feed and skeletal data together.
NUI_INITIALIZE(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR) gives you color data, you can only initialize the camera once. So it is either the video feed or the skeleton coordinates.

I tried to find the solution but i can't find any.

Note: I don't have any use of RGB except for preview so i can see the virtual object, since i'll be using the skeleton data to get the hand coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer:

```
NuiInitialize(NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_COLOR|NUI_INITIALIZE_FLAG_USES_SKELETON);
```

This will allow use of both the data.